# Accessing Scanners in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, swift, wia, image-scanner

I'm primarily a windows developer but I need to port an app to the mac platform.
The app needs access to any scanners plugged into the computer. On windows, I've made use of the WIA library. I was wondering if the mac platform has an equivalent and also if it has bindings for the new Swift language?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access scanners and other devices using [ImageKit + ImageCaptureCore](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/02Overview/02Overview.html). Some of Apple's documentation is very sparse, so you shouldn't be afraid to learn things from the header files (e.g. `ICScannerDevice.h`). It might help to look at some of the code I wrote for [this application](https://github.com/counsyl/scanstream), particularly [this file](https://github.com/counsyl/scanstream/blob/master/ScanStream/SSScanManager.m).

There is no such thing as "bindings" for Swift, since Swift currently uses the Objective-C runtime and interacts directly with Objective-C. [This guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) will help.